# png, jpg images not displaying properly in pygame (mac osx pycharm / IDLE)

Tags: python, macos, pygame, pycharm

recently started coding with python using pycharm / python IDLE on mac osx.

When it comes to showing / blitting images onto a defined pygame display, png and jpg formats don't appear properly (see images).

Only bmp formats appear properly.

Any suggestions to make jpg and png appear correctly in pygame?

Thank you

[source jpg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCoiZ.jpg)

[how it appears on pygame display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrJuM.png)

```
import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()

    width = 640
    height = 480

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('hello piggy')

    white = (255,255,255)
    image = pygame.image.load("flpig.jpg")

    x=160
    y=120

    running = True

    while running:
        screen.fill(white)
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You are changing the x and y co-ordinates 60 times a second in the while loop.. It starts off as "right" and updates that, and then goes through the others, down, left, up.  this changes the x and y co-ordinates. Then you blit the image using those co-ordinates.  Try changing `fpsClock.tick(FPS)` to `fpsClock.tick(3)` to see if you can see what these rapid updates are doing.

Comment: Also, as answered below, you should use a running variable, and set it to True for your loop.

Comment: Thanks Marienbad. I have simplified the code to a bare minimum, only to display the image. It still shows the jpg and png images in a distorted way, as shown in attached image in my question. I wonder what could fix this, really keen on using png in my pygames...

Comment: What happens if you do this: pygame.image.load('flpig.jpg').convert() ?

Comment: Same, same. Image is still not displaying correctly...

Comment: You can use pillow to load your image. Try this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976371/how-to-display-images-loaded-with-pillow-with-pygame-in-python-3-7)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
img = pygame.image.load("flpig.jpg")
white = (255, 255, 255)
w = 640
h = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
screen.fill((white))
running = 1

while running:
 screen.fill((white))
 screen.blit(img,(0,0))
 pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks Moo, but the jpg image is alas still not displaying properly