# How to display Images loaded with Pillow with Pygame in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, pygame, png, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I imported an image to my project using

```
from PIL import Image
myImage = Image.open("myImageDirectory.png")
```

So myImage is now imported as a png file. But I want to display it to the Screen using Pygame. Normally I use

```
import pygame
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
win.blit(myImage, (50, 50))
```

Now I get the Error that the function needs a surface, not a png File.
Has anyone an idea how I can convert the image to a surface or how I can display it?

I tried not much yet​ because I didn't found anything that could solve my problem.

Edit:

[What is wrong with this way that I get the error: Couldn't open bg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FijU.png)

Comment: I don't get it. What is the reason that you don't use [`pygame.image.load()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load)

Comment: Because you can't import png and jpg with the Pygame module. See this: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html When you can tell me how I can import it although with Pygame I'm happy.

Comment: Nonsense, I do it almost every day. From your link *"[...] can support the following formats. JPG PNG [...]"*

Comment: By default, it can only load uncompressed BMP images. No, it can't load PNG only with the full build. What I found all called Pillow aka PIL the full build. When I run it with the Pygame import I get the error: Couldn't open myImage.png

Comment: Can you look at the Image above and please tell me what I do wrong. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [PIL and pygame.image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25202092/pil-and-pygame-image). Use [`Image.tobytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) get the image data as a bytes object and [`pygame.image.fromstring()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.fromstring) to load the data to an [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pygame
```

```py
pilImage = Image.open("myImageDirectory.png")
myImage = pygame.image.fromstring(pilImage.tobytes(), pilImage.size, pilImage.mode)
```